# fetch Data during the generation in Nuxt 3

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

How can I get data only while generating a static page in Nuxt3. After generation, the data should be stored in the source code, i.e. the fetch command should be replaced by the fetched object. How is it possible in Nuxt3?

```html
<template>
  <main>
    {{ page.content }
  </main>
</template>

<script setup>

const { data: page } = await useFetch(`http://api.example/pages/index`, { headers: { 'api-key': api.key }});

</script>
```

Comment: You can save confidential data only using Nuxt 3 server/API. Nuxt 3 SSR was not meant to be used with confidential data. You can use pre-render functionality like in answer below if you want to have already rendered HTML files for app.

Answer (score 0):

You can just run `npm run generate`, this will make the API call and build the page with all data during the build.

In `.output/public/index.html` you now see everything in there. You can now host this folder on any hosting site.

In an alternative, you can run `npm run preview` this will spin up a server with the index.html file, and you can right-click and check the page source.

There's also manual pre-rendering by adding this to `nuxt.config.ts`

[pre rendering docs](https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/deployment#manual-pre-rendering)

```js
  nitro: {
     prerender: {
        routes: ['/user/1', '/user/2']
     }
  }
```

Please have a look at the documentation on Nuxt [website](https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/deployment#crawl-based-pre-rendering)

Comment: Yes, it is pre-rendered, but the fetch command is also in the outputted JavaScript Code. My API-Key is defined in the runtimeConfig, so that I become an undefined error. The API URL is also recognizable. But this should also not be visible.

Comment: You can't hide these things in client side, you just have to make sure it's a public key. If it's a private key you need to configure this on your backend and set up authentication. Also the backend should manage what data you can retrieve using the public key